# Problem with collection of forms Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony5

I've got some problem with symfony 5. 2 entitites(post and creator).

Post entity

```
 <?php
    
         
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PostRepository::class)
     */
    class Post
    {
        public const PUBLISHED = 1;
        public const DRAFT = 0;
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1000)
         */
        private $title;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         */
        private $year;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Creator", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        private $creator;
    

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $update_at;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
         */
        private $is_published;
    
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->creator = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        public function getTitle(): ?string
        {
            return $this->title;
        }
    
        public function setTitle(string $title): self
        {
            $this->title = $title;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getYear(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->year;
        }
    
        public function setYear(\DateTimeInterface $year): self
        {
            $this->year = $year;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
       
        /**
         * @param Creator $creator
         * @return Post
         */
        public function addCreator(Creator $creator)
        {
            $this->creator[] = $creator;
            $creator->setPost($this);
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Creator $creator
         */
        public function removeCreator(Creator $creator)
        {
            $this->creator->removeElement($creator);
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection
         */
        public function getCreator()
        {
            return $this->creator;
        }
    
        public function getUpdateAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->update_at;
        }
    
        public function setUpdateAtValue()
        {
            $this->update_at = new \DateTime();
        }
    
        public function setUpdateAt(?\DateTimeInterface $update_at): self
        {
            $this->update_at = $update_at;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getIsPublished(): ?bool
        {
            return $this->is_published;
        }
    
        public function setIsPublished()
        {
            $this->is_published = self::PUBLISHED;
        }
    
        public function setIsDraft()
        {
            $this->is_published = self::DRAFT;
        }
    }
```

Creator Entity

```
   <?php
    
     namespace App\Entity;
    
     use App\Repository\CreatorRepository;
     use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    
     /**
      * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CreatorRepository::class)
      */
     class Creator
     {
        public const PUBLISHED= 1;
        public const DRAFT = 0;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $user;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $name;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $surname;
    
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $participation;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
         */
        private $is_published;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $create_at;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $update_at;
    
    
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="creator")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $post;
    
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
    
        public function getUser(): ?string
        {
            return $this->user;
        }
    
        public function setUser(string $user): self
        {
            $this->user = $user;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
    
        public function setName(?string $name): self
        {
            $this->name = $name;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getSurname(): ?string
        {
            return $this->surname;
        }
    
        public function setSurname(?string $surname): self
        {
            $this->surname = $surname;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getIsPublished(): ?bool
        {
            return $this->is_published;
        }
    
        public function setIsPublished()
        {
            $this->is_published = self::PUBLISHED;
        }
    
        public function setIsDraft()
        {
            $this->is_published = self::DRAFT;
        }
    
        public function getCreateAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->create_at;
        }
    
        public function setCreateAtValue()
        {
            $this->create_at = new \DateTime();
        }
    
        public function setCreateAt(\DateTimeInterface $create_at): self
        {
            $this->create_at = $create_at;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getUpdateAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->update_at;
        }
    
        public function setUpdateAtValue()
        {
            $this->update_at = new \DateTime();
        }
    
        public function setUpdateAt(\DateTimeInterface $update_at): self
        {
            $this->update_at = $update_at;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getParticipation(): ?string
        {
            return $this->participation;
        }
    
        public function setParticipation(string $participation): self
        {
            $this->participation = $participation;
    
            return $this;
        }
 
        /**
         * @return Post
         */
        public function getPost()
        {
            return $this->post;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Post $post
         * @return Creator
         */
        public function setPost(Post $post = null)
        {
            $this->post = $post;
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Post $post
         */
        public function removePost(Post $post)
        {
            $this->post->removeElement($post);
        }
    }
```

Post controller :

```
       /**
     * @Route("/admin/post", name="admin_post")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $forRender = parent::renderDefault();
        $forRender['title'] = 'Wszystkie publikacje';
        $forRender['post'] = $this->postRepository->getAllPost();
        $forRender['check_creator'] = $this->creatorRepository->getAllCreator();
        return $this->render('admin/post/index.html.twig', $forRender);
    }
```

Twig:

```
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Akcja</th>
            <th>Tytul</th>
            <th>Rok</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Konferencja</th>
            {% for check_creators in check_creator %}
            <th>Kto stworzył</th>
            <th>Udział</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for post_item in post %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('admin_post_update', {'id': post_item.id}) }}" class="btn-link">Modyfikuj</a></td>
            <td>{{ post_item.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ post_item.year|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
            <td>{{ post_item.numOfPoints }}</td>
            <td>{{ post_item.conference }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for check_creators in check_creator %}
            <td>{{ check_creators.user }}</td>
            <td>{{ check_creators.participation }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The data that I have in the database for some reason stuck together in the last column. How to make the data in the right place. Screens below

https://snipboard.io/MpzZHO.jpg

https://snipboard.io/0Y5Cyh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if entities are related you can get creators from post, so there's no need to call getAllCreator in controller. Once you have your posts all you do in twig to get creators is

```
{{ post.creators }}
```

or

```
{% for creator in post.creators %}
```

Now, are you sure you want one post to have many creators (OneToMany relation on Post)? Can you show what an expected result would look like? Just write an example row or two based on the screenshots you provided.

Comment: 1.Yeah, finally got it. Change my {% for check_creator in check_creator %} to {% check_creators in post_item.creator %} .
2. Definetelly, I have many creators to one post(many creators like I have 1 document but many creators of them like declaration of Independence

Answer (score 0):

Try this method too

```
 /**
     * @Route("/admin/post", name="admin_post")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $forRender = parent::renderDefault();
        $forRender['title'] = 'Wszystkie publikacje';
        $forRender['post'] = $this->postRepository->getAllPost();
        $forRender['check_creator'] = $this->creatorRepository->getAllCreator();
        return $this->render('admin/post/index.html.twig',
           'post'=>$forRender
        );
    }
```